# Bot renaming user by user's command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been having a problem with some project I 've been doing for the last 3-4 days on discord. It has to do with bots of course and the language I chose is javascript (discord.js).

So, the thing seems kinda simple but I am really stuck in this cause I have only a little experience with javascript.

The bot is supposed to read two values on a message, those values are a string and a number. The bot will simply nickname you the string and that number.

example: User says: john123 40
         bot: renaming the user as " John123 | 40 "

The nicknaming command and such are the easy part, the hard one for me is how should I tell the bot "take the string, put it left of the "|", take the number, put it right of the "|" ". I mean the bot can't even read them. Here is my try:

```
var name = message.content.includes(String)
var number = message.content.includes("1"|| "2"|| "3"|| "4"|| "5"|| "6"|| "7"|| "8"|| "9"|| "10"|| "11"|| "12"|| "13"|| "14"|| "15"|| "16"|| "17"|| "18"|| "19"|| "20"|| "21"|| "22"|| "23"|| "24"|| "25"|| "26"|| "27"|| "28"|| "29"|| "30"|| "31"|| "32"|| "33"|| "34"|| "35"|| "36"|| "37"|| "38"|| "39"|| "40")


function theNaming (name, number){
message.member.setNickname('name'|' number')
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);
}
```

(the level is supposed to not go higher than 40 so, I thought it may work inside the include)

Comment: maybe `name = message.content.split(' ')[0];` and `number = message.content.split(' ')[1];`

Comment: Check out my answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: As a matter of fact I am doing it right now, it seems to work as expected on theory but visual studio shows me some errors i can't quite understand, such as "message.member.setNickname" is not a function.

Comment: ok i think this is as far as i can go, seems like i am missing something i can't see, i've left the script as it is now on pastebin (or at least a part of it). https://pastebin.com/Wy7UGgrB

Comment: @ScarletD. - I looked at that pastebin link. The reason for that error is `message.member` is undefined.  This is because of `var message = message.content;` statement where you reassigned other value to message. Delete the above line and use `var words = message.content.split(' ');`. This will fix that error.

Comment: And yeah you can now officially call me stupid XD. I really thought this had no effect in the actual script for god's sake! It works as intented without any fault. The only thing I am kinda worried about is that if the user just give one word instead of two it will just become john123 undefined. Just an if statement would be enought to prevent this from happening, I will be working on it

Comment: Haha, nice to know it is working. I'm glad it helped. Yes, you should have checks to handle such cases. Keep going!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I tell the bot "take the string, put it left of the "|",
>   take the number, put it right of the "|" ". I mean the bot can't even
>   read them.

The bot can read them if you pass the message in proper format. Your question should have mentioned that `name` and `number` will be separated by space. This is how the bot recognizes `name` and `number` from entered message.

[String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can be use to split the message string into `name` and `number`.

```js
var message = "john123 40";
var words = message.split(' '); // Using space as the separator.

console.log(words);
```

Now `words` array contains strings from the message which are separated by space. And you can access them using their index.

```
var name = words[0];
var number = words[1];
```

Then pass them as arguments to the naming function like `theNaming(name, number);`